# How can I rename a directory name replacing the first letter of each word in the name string to uppercase?

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, cmd.exe, batch-rename

On a Windows 10 computer, I've been using free utilities like PFrank tool and Power Toys PowerRenamer. With PFrank I was able to change the case of each word in the name of the filenames to uppercase, but it won't change the directory names.

Please do you know of a command or script in Powershell, CMD or BASH (using Windows subsystem linux), to accomplish that? or a tool (preferable open source), that can do that. Since I already change the filenames I want to do this recursively on the directory names only.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very common and easy thing. Just use substring and the ToUpper/ToTitleCase method. Just do a search for `'PowerShell capitalizing the first letter of a string'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from my comment. It's simply this.

***Update***

***Removed original long answer and replacing with the below to address your comment:***

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Directory -Recurse) -match 'src|dest' | 
ForEach-Object {
    "Proccessing $($PSItem.FullName) to TitleCase"
    $renameItemTempSplat = @{
        Path     = $PSitem.FullName
        NewName  = "$((Get-Culture).Textinfo.ToTitleCase($PSitem.Name.ToLower()))1"
        #WhatIf   = $true 
    }
    Rename-Item @renameItemTempSplat -PassThru | 
    Rename-Item -NewName $($((Get-Culture).Textinfo.ToTitleCase($PSitem.Name.ToLower())) -replace '1')
}
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Directory -Recurse) -match 'src|dest'
# Results
<#
Proccessing D:\Temp\dest to TitleCase
Proccessing D:\Temp\Destination to TitleCase
Proccessing D:\Temp\src to TitleCase


    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         12-Oct-20     14:27                Dest
d-----         24-Jan-21     22:24                Destination
d-----         12-Oct-20     13:27                Src
#>
```

[About WhatIf/Confirm](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell%20-WhatIf%2FConfirm%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: postanote following your idea, created this script but then I got an error that says that the source and the destination path must be different:

`$dirtree = Get-childitem 'G:\Music\MIDI' -Directory -Recurse
ForEach($dirname in $dirtree){
 $capdirname = (Get-Culture).textinfo.totitlecase($dirname.BaseName.tolower())
 Rename-item -Path $dirname.Fullname -NewName $capdirname
 }`

Comment: You've overcomplicated this and thus have syntax issues. See my updated example for you to try. Again, remember, `Never ever run destructive code (add/new, rename/move, create/delete, etc...) unless you check yourself first. If you don't, you could/can cause serious damage to your environment/files.`

Comment: Same result, after removing the whatif I got the same error message: "Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different."

Comment: Windows will not allow directories of the same name; since Windows is not case-sensitive, thus it's a two-step process for your use case. See my update for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Kernel32` method `MoveFile` to rename files and directories without the need to rename it twice.

The following code renames files and directories using the respective properties for the new name (depending on the type).

> The method 'MoveFile' actually triggers the same process as doing it interactively using the Windows Explorer.

```powershell
# "MoveFile" works for files and folders

# only add type once
if ($null -eq ('Win32.Kernel32' -as [type])) {
    # add method 'MoveFile from' kernel32.dll
    # https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefile
    $signature = @'
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool MoveFile(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName);
'@
    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace Win32
}

$dirPath = 'C:\temp\CaseTest'
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dirPath -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $parentPath = $currentName = $fileExtension = $null

    if ($_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
        # Directories
        $parentPath  = $_.Parent.FullName
        $currentName = $_.Name

    } elseif ($_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo]) {
        # Files
        $parentPath    = $_.Directory.FullName
        $currentName   = $_.BaseName
        $fileExtension = $_.Extension
    }

    if ($null -notin $currentName, $parentPath) {
        $newName =  @(
            [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase($currentName.ToLower()),
            $fileExtension
        ) -join ''

        $newPath    = Join-Path -Path $parentPath -ChildPath $newName
        $moveResult = [Win32.Kernel32]::MoveFile($_.FullName, $newPath)

        if (-not $moveResult) {
            # 'MoveFile' returns only $false in case of errors, 
            # so we have to build the respective exception.
            # This requires "SetLastError = true" in signature
            $win32Error     = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetLastWin32Error()
            $win32Exception = [System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception]$win32Error
            Write-Error -Exception $win32Exception `
                -Message "$($win32Exception.Message) `"$($_.FullName)`""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: True, and I did stuff like this as well via WMI and VBS, etc back in the day, but that is way more work, and one could just download one of the many bulk rename tools and write no code at all. Leveraging raw .Net and other classes (including any custom classes one may have written) is cool, I do that as needed, but really overkill for this simple use case. Thinking out of the box is not a bad thing at all, yet, 10 lines vs almost 50 lines, well, you know. My rule is, write code for those who will follow you, who have to maintain it, don't assume they can do what you do or know or want to.know.

Comment: ... well, that and using only native PowerShell Cmdlets only. Thus, no C# / Classes level knowledge needed. We all have our choices and need to use what works for us, regardless of what anyone else says/believes, does, pontificates, etc. Good stuff though for folks who did not know, to know.